# Phalcon 3.x PHP7 (Redis) Session issues

Tags: php, session, redis, phalcon

I am moving a development project to a new Vagrant environment going from PHP5.x to PHP7.0.8 running under Apache2 on Ubuntu 16.04 and Phalcon 2.x to Phalcon 3.x.

All seems to be working fine except I am getting session errors e.g. `session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed.  ID: user (path: /tmp)` when calling `$this->_session->regenerateId();`. I am using Phalcon's Redis session adapter (with Redis 2.2.8-devphp7 installed).

Searching online I have come across similar issues with Redis and Memcached on PHP7, but these issues date back to late last year, early this year when Redis and Memcached were still updating to support PHP7, and I haven't seen any more recent issues. From what I have read, PHP7 handles sessions in a stricter way and complains if it doesn't get exactly the correct response - a string apparently.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?